# Private key opens a different address than the one that it "should"

Tags: wallets, addresses, private-key, import

I have a small problem (hope it doesn't prove to be huge) with importing wallets using private keys.

I am not the most knowledgeable when it comes to Ethereum, and was hoping you guys could maybe help me. I have created a wallet on Exodus some time ago, and sent funds to that wallet. I have lost access to that wallet because I did the most rookie mistake of not backing up my mnemonic phrase / seed as soon as I created the wallet and my laptop had to mess up before I took any backups of the phrase BUT I have the address and the private key (which I thought was a solid backup option as well).

The thing is that, whenever I try to fetch my funds into any other wallet (I have tried MetaMask, Trust wallet, and Exodus), the private key opens a different address than the one it is supposed to open except on Exodus where it says that the key is invalid (but I guess that isn't related to my issue because ertain Exodus versions have this bug).

I am quite sure my private address is correct, I have copy and pasted it from Exodus (and I took a screenshot of the revealed private key for that address through Exodus as well to make sure), so it isn't an issue of a wrong private key at all.

This isn't my first time using private keys, but this is definitely the first time this happens to me. I have found a few threads online regarding this, but none offered any solutions really. It says almost everywhere that a private key is supposed to lead only to two addresses; one from the hash of the compressed public key, and one from the uncompressed one, and Ethereum uses the uncompressed one so basically the public key should lead only to one address.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to unlock a certain address using its private key?

Comment: Are you sure it is the Ethereum private key? A BIP39 standard compliant wallet will generate different private keys for different coins. I don't know about Exodus but there are wallet that are not compliant or use a slightly different algorithm an their addresses are not compatible with other wallets.

Comment: @Ismael Yes I am sure it is an ethereum private key. Exodus does provide a BIP39 compatible seed mnemonic which I have lost sadly. Aren't my addresses (and private keys) all derived from that phrase?

Comment: All addresses and private keys are derived from the same seed phrase, but each coin has its separate branch. The Bitcoin private keys will be different from the Ethereum private key, etc.

Comment: @Ismael yes I know that and I am sure that what I have is my eth key. When you expose the keys for a certain coin on Exodus, it shows you a table that has your addresses, the balance for every address, and the private key for every address. I only had one eth address on Exodus, and that address shows the correct amount of eth I have, and that's the address whose key I have now.